# How to compare binary registry key value in Chef InSpec?

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

If I have a registry key with a `REG_BINARY` property value of `01 00 00 00`, when I compare that value in InSpec, do I compare with that binary value as well? Or does it get converted?

e.g. should my test be

```rb
describe registry_key('...') do
  its('value_here') { should eq '01 00 00 00' }
end
```

or should the comparison part be:

```rb
its('value_here') { should eq 1 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InSpec appears to return it as an array, so the check should be:

```rb
its('value_here') { should eq [1,0,0,0] }
```